# USB Mouse not recognized at boot-up

Tags: boot, 13.10, mouse

When I boot up my system, the mouse cursor does not appear.  If I then manually unplug and then replug the mouse, the mouse cursor appears and I can use it.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a system with the following specs:

```
motherboard: Asus Z87-Pro  
CPU: i7-4770K  
memory: 16GB  
graphics: GeForce GTX 770  
disk: samsung 840 solid state 500GB drive (primary) + 2 WD 3TB sata drives  
keyboard/mouse: logitech MK120  (USB)
```

I tried swapping out the mouse for a different brand, but this did not help.  I also tried disabling legacy USB in the BIOS, but this did not help either.

Thanks in advance from a long-ago unix hacker for any advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Comment: where do you plug your mouse which usb port

Comment: There are a total of eight USB ports.  Four are on the left corner of the motherboard and are labeled "USB 3.0/UASP", two are near the right side of the motherboard ("USB BIOS Flashback"), and the remaining two are on the front of the case.  When the mouse is plugged into any of the four USB 3.0/UASP ports, it exhibits the problem that I described.  When it is plugged into any of the others, the mouse is usable upon boot.  So, as a practical matter, the problem is solved for me.  However, it would be interesting to know why the USB 3.0/UASP ports do not seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB 3.0 legacy support in the BIOS if it offers such an option.

Some boards do implement BIOS level "legacy" support which allows keyboards and mice to work on USB 3.0 ports. I've seen it, but it doesn't always work.

Until native core-logic-chipset-based USB 3.0 support arrives, the only option is to have keyboard and mouse plugged in to USB 2.0 ports.  Current chipsets from both Intel and AMD lack native USB 3.0 support.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  For what it's worth, enabling USB 3.0 legacy support does not seem to make a difference on this motherboard.